# Laravel 5 saving factory data with oneToMany relation set 0 in relation field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I create two models with oneToMany relation Text and TextMain (texts_main.text_id = texts.id)

**Text.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Text extends Model{

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table = 'texts';
    protected $fillable = [

        'text', 
        'lang_id'
    ];
    protected $dates = [

        'deleted_at'
    ];
}
```

**TextMain.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TextMain extends Model{

    protected $table = 'texts_main';
    protected $fillable = [

        'user_id',
        'text_id'
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function texts() {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Text', 'id', 'text_id');
    }
}
```

Then I define two factories

```
$factory->define(App\Models\Text::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    return [

        'text'      => $faker->paragraph,
        'lang_id'   => 1
    ];
});


$factory->define(App\Models\TextMain::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {

    return [

        'user_id'   => 1
    ];
});
```

In my seeder php file

```
public function run()
{
    factory(TextMain::class, 5)->create()
        ->each(function($tm) {

        $tm->texts()
            ->save(factory(Text::class)->make());
    });
}
```

but when i start migration and seeding in table "texts_main" field for relation "text_id" equals to 0.

How can I change code to fix this?
Thanks in advance:)

UPD:

```
    Schema::create('texts', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();

        $table->longText('text');
        $table->integer('lang_id');
    });

    Schema::create('texts_main', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->integer('text_id');
    });
```

Comment: Could you post your migrations table set also? You may have a foreing key in Text pointing to TextMain and then in seeder you may use something like `rand(1,5)` to fulfill that value.

Comment: Ok, I update post with migrations